# How to get the string outside two markers using python regular experssions?

Tags: python, arrays, regex, string

For example, let's say I have the following string:
`str1 = "There are !27 papers in! the book !right! now. !Also a marker.!"`,
I would like it to return a list of the words outside the '!' markers. 
So for this particular question: `["There", "are", "the", "book", "now"]`

I've tried python regular expression using `re.findall('!(.+?)!', str1)` but that's returning what's inside the '!' not the ones outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be close enough, but not using re

```
[s for w in str1.split('!')[::2] for s in w.split()]
```

Even using re you need spend efforts to cleanse the result of punctuations.

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest way would be to substitute.**

```
str1 = "There are !27 papers in! the book !right! now. !Also a marker.!"
re.sub(r'(!.+?!)','',str1)
```